# How to update a value in a table with angular js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I'm using PHP/MySQL/Socket.IO/NodeJS. I'm trying to expand my website and add more functionality to it. Essentially I need to update a table when a new user is added to the table, but I need to do it with AngularJS I'm pretty sure.

```
<pre>
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Risk</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr><td> Joe </td> <td> 5 </td> 
</tbody>
```

So as you can see Joe has a "Risk" Value of 5 this could change based on a couple different things. I need to know of a way to change Joe's value when a socket event is called with AngularJS or if there is another way that would be easier that would work.

Answer (score 1):

You have a javascript model with the data and when you update the data, the view will be updated respectively. After incoming socket, you just update the $scope.users.

In your controller:

```
$scope.users = [
  { name: 'Joe', risk: 5 }
];
```

In your template:

```
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Risk</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.risk }}</td> 
</tbody>
```

Comment: How would I populate the users model as it comes in though?